# Get error trying to create a share link with action.createLink with onedrive for business but can retrieve existing link if created in the portal

Tags: onedrive, office365-apps, office365api

I'm getting an Internal Server Error 500 with error message "host web isn’t a personal site" when trying to create a share link with the OneDrive for Business root url - https://{tenant}-my.sharepoint.com/_api/v2.0

I can upload / create files via the above API but I cannot create a shared link. If I create the link using the Office365 OneDrive portal I can then retrieve the link with action.createLink.

using the Office 365 Developer Pack subsciption but the file that I can upload and update but not create a link for is definitely in OneDrive and not the team site.

Anyone else getting the same problem and have answers? Not sure what extra detail I can provide here.

Any help is greatly appreciated. This has stumped me for a couple of days now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft have confirmed that this is a bug in the OneDrive api with the 'createLink' function.

Refer this: https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-api-docs/issues/237#issuecomment-152639588

Apparently the fix is a few days away. Hope that helps somebody.

Cheers